# Apple Configurator 2 DEP and Restore To Image

Tags: mdm, apple-configurator

Using the new version 2, I can't seem to do what I need to do.  Our devices are DEP enrolled, so I need to be able to automatically prepare the devices to enroll them in DEP and enroll into MDM.  I've done this using a blueprint, ok so far.  At this point they are supervised and not able to have the MDM profiles removed.  Now I need to apply an image on top.  This image has certain backgrounds, apps in different folders, volume all the way up and other custom settings for accessibility.

The 2nd step is what I cannot figure out.  The blueprint lets you prepare OR restore with a backup, but not both.  Configurator is requiring to restore with a backup.  Which removes my previous prepare.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to supervision on an iOS device, you cannot restore a backup to the device.  You are correct in the fact that you can only do one or the other but not both.  The device will inherit it's supervision state from the backup that is being restored to it, so that when you restore an unsupervised backup to a supervised device, it essentially wipes out the supervision state.  The only way around this is to restore an iCloud backup that was done from another device.  This can only be done through iCloud and not through iTunes.

You can do it but it is a pain and requires you to have a device that acts a surrogate for your iCloud backup.